# Scrolling on webview not working

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview on my 4.1.2 Android, which I load with

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);


        final WebView wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        String sHTML="Webviewtest";
        for(int i=0;i<500;i++){
            sHTML=sHTML+"Line " + i + "<br>";
        }

        wv.loadData(sHTML, "text/html", null);
        wv.setScrollY(1500);

        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

             @Override  
             public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                 super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                 wv.setScrollY(500);
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done! " + wv.getScrollY(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             }  

             });
    }
}
```

I like the webview to scroll down to a specific postition, but it stays on the top.
any ideas ? 
When setScrollY() with a button it works, but I like to set the position after laoding the HTML. I also tried to do it with a Handler, which I call in onPageFinished. This does not work too.

I created a very simple Android project, where everyone can download and test:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7yz_IQ1CMblUU03cGd5cEotTVE&usp=sharing

Comment: Why do you call `super.onPageFinished(view, url);` at the end? Have you tried calling it in the beginning. and `setScrollY` is a API level 14 call. Are you on a device which as API 14?

Comment: I tried both. At the beginning and at the end. No success. Yes my device is API14. I can also see that when debugging.

Answer (score 2):

This time it is not android's fault,it has provided us with another approach.
try:

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView v, String url) {   
 v.evaluateJavascript("window.scrollTo(0,"+expectedPos/a.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density+");", null);
 super.onPageFinished(v, url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Solution. I don't like it, but it works. All this mess because of the android framework, that doesn't work like expected...

I added a AsyncTask:

```
private class Waitforloaded extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {


         protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

         }

         protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {

         }

        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean bgo=true;
            int iTries=0;
            while(bgo){
                iTries=iTries+1;
                if(iTries>20 || wv.getContentHeight()>0){
                    bgo=false;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            wv.setScrollY(1500);
            return null;
        }
     }
```

Then calling it in

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

             @Override  
             public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                 super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                 Waitforloaded wfl=new Waitforloaded();
                 wfl.execute("");


             }
```

Answer (score 0):

WebView.setScrollY works for me only when I give it some delay with a timer after the WebView is loaded:

```
        webView.loadData(sHtmlTemplate, "text/html", "utf-8");

        Timer t = new Timer(false);
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainActivity.mainactivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        webView.setScrollY(500);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 300); // 300 ms delay before scrolling
```